# Scale TextBox on RenderTargetBitmap without loss of quality

Tags: c#, uwp, textbox, uwp-xaml, rendertargetbitmap

Does anybody know if there is a way to ensure that `TextBoxes` scale nicely on `RenderTargetBitmap`?

See my code below, I am attempting to produce an output file of a Canvas with various different elements in it.

`Images` scale perfectly fine with no loss of quality at all, same with my `InkCanvas`. But `TextBoxes` just don't scale well at all.

```
RenderTargetBitmap renderTargetBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap();
//Produce a PNG output with a pixel size of 5x the onscreen canvas
await renderTargetBitmap.RenderAsync(MaskArea, (int)MaskArea.Width * 5, (int)MaskArea.Height * 5);

var pixelBuffer = await renderTargetBitmap.GetPixelsAsync();
var pixels = pixelBuffer.ToArray();
var displayInformation = DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView();

var folder = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFolderAsync("Print", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
var file = await folder.CreateFileAsync("Canvas" + ".png", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
using (var stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
 {
    var encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.PngEncoderId, stream);
    encoder.BitmapTransform.InterpolationMode = BitmapInterpolationMode.Cubic;
    encoder.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, BitmapAlphaMode.Premultiplied, (uint)renderTargetBitmap.PixelWidth, (uint)renderTargetBitmap.PixelHeight, displayInformation.RawDpiX, displayInformation.RawDpiY, pixels);
    await encoder.FlushAsync();
 }
```

I can't really understand why my InkCanvas in particular renders perfectly but yet TextBoxes lose quality. 
As a footnote, I'm aware that one way around it would be to manually add the Text to my output file afterwards with Win2D but I just thought I'd check here first in case I'm missing something.

Thanks

**Output** (You may have to click on the image to see the quality loss)
[image: Output]

Comment: I've tested the [BitmapEncoder options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/bitmapencoder-options-reference) and I can get jpeg to use ImageQuality=1 which makes textbox shows more clear. However png does not support ImageQUality. So a workaround maybe use jpeg first and then convert it to png. Is this reasonable to you?

Comment: @BarryWang-MSFT Thanks for your suggestion, as it stands a JPG would be fine for my needs also, however the ImageQuality setting hasn't helped the TextBox issues and my output remains more or less the same.

Comment: Yep. Definitely the quality is not that good when I zoom to see the image. Either RenderTargetBitmap or BitmapEncoder seems haven't provided us other ways to raise the quality. I would think that maybe you need to consider Win2D now.